# Column count doesn't match, But I don't want to overwrite the first two columns

Tags: php, mysql

**The Problem:** I can't insert data into my table ignoring the `PID` and `PRIMARY KEY`. I thought that since these two values are auto_incremented that they are accounted for automatically. 
What I am doing incorrectly in my `INSERT` query?

**The Table**

```
"CREATE TABLE pictures
(
    PID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(PID),
    url CHAR(255),
    description TEXT
)"
```

**Insert Query**

```
"INSERT INTO pictures VALUES( 'url', 'other')"; 
// As expected I'm only initailizing url and description.
```

**edit:** I know of the syntax where you can explicitly define what columns you are setting. Is it not possible to implicitly ignore the first two columns?

Comment: It's one column, really: `PID`, not two. Your table has got three columns.

Comment: Oh okay, that's something that confused me. So the line `PRIMARY KEY()` isn't actually a column, but a variable being set too `PID` ?

Comment: That line is only defining a `primary key` on your `PID` column (that's not another column)

Comment: The PRIMARY KEY directive can be included on PID column def, ex. PID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution would be to define columns in INSERT command

```
INSERT INTO pictures (`url`, `description`) VALUES ('xxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');
```

The second solution would be to put empty PID (will be generated by database)

```
INSERT INTO pictures VALUES ('', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');
```

Comment: use tick instead of quote around fields?

Comment: I just tried your second solution and got quite a weird error. `Notice: Undefined index: offset `

Comment: Wait, I'm sorry that's because of unrelated code. Anyhow, it looks as though your code worked. Thank you!